# How to play sound alert in an angular 4 project?

Tags: angular

I want to hear notification sound while getting new messages,is there any packages available for play notification audio alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install it to your project with `npm install --save howler` and play a sound like this:

```js
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.mp3']
});

sound.play();
```